# How to convert plain text hyperlink to html hyperlink in java?

Tags: java

can anyone advise on how to improve the below regular expression to easily convert plain text hyperlinks to html hyperlinks in java?

```
message = message.replaceAll("(?:https?|http?)://[\\w/%.\\-?&=!#]+(?!.*\\[/)", 
"$0");
```

Actually i am wondering if it is possible to just check whether just convert any text found with http or https together with the appending text without the spacing instead of checking for those special characters.

I saw some websites textareas that can easily convert plain text hyperlink to html hyperlink. But i have been researching on stackoverflow and i didnt really find any complete answer on this issue.

I want the java regular expresion to be able to autmatically detect the links and convert them to html hyperlinks which are clickable.

```
|http://naishe.blogspot.com| 
|http://tw.com/#!/someTEXTs| 
|http://ts123t1.rapi.com/#!download|13321|1313|fairy_tale.mp4| 
|http://www.google.com| 
|https://www.google.com| 
|google.com| 
|google.com| 
|google.com/test| 
|123.com/test| 
|ex-ample.com| 
|http://ex-ample.com/test-url_chars?param1=val1&;par2=val+with%20spaces| 
https://www.google.com.sg/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=test&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&gs_l=&psj=1&fp=1&biw=1366&bih=638&bav=on.2,or.r_ gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&cad=b
```

Comment: Are the pipes (`|`) part of the link definition? If not, how should any program know that `google.com` would be a link and not just some text, e.g. a key or so? - And what do you mean with converting those to html links? Do you mean `http://www.google.com -> <a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>`? If so, where's the problem besides detecting links?

Comment: Ok e.g. consider the code text in my question. They could be part of the text that user entered. Meaning those content of the text that start with http or https should be converted to <a href=""></a> html format hyperlink automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `http://www.google.com` should be identified as a link but `www.google.com` not, you could use something like this:

```
String htmlLink = link.replaceAll("(?:https|http)://([\\w/%.\\-?&=!#]+(?!.*\\[/))", 
                                  "<a href=\"$0\">$1</a>");
```

Output:

```
http://www.google.com -> <a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
www.google.com -> www.google.com
```

**Edit**:

It might be possible to simplify the expression to something like this:

```
String pattern = "(?:https|http)://([^\\s\\|]+)";
```

This expression would match anything that starts with `http` or `https` followed by `://` and a sequence of one or more characters that are not whitespace or a pipe. If there are other characters that should not be allowed (I didn't check the spec for which that are) just list them in the brackets (between `[^]` and `]`).

Comment: @dfdf it's basically yours with the `?` removed after `https` and `http` as well as an additional capturing group after the `://` part (hence the `$1`).